# Update generic property of generic class?

Tags: c#, dynamic, propertychanged, generics

I'm quite new at C# `Generic Classes` so I don't know if we can update the generic property of a generic class dynamically?

Let say I have a class

```
A { long id; long count; }
```

Can we write an extension that update the given property by 1 so

```
A.AddOne(a => a.id); will change A {id=1, count=1} to A {id=2, count=1}

and

A.AddOne(a => a.count); will change A {id=1, count=1} to A {id=1, count=2}
```

Any helps would be appreciated!

Comment: In what way is this class generic?

Comment: I think you are really confusing `Generic`. The stuff you are trying to do is actually `lambda` methods (`x=>x.id`). You will need to deal with `linq expressions` and `Func` delegates. More light on these can be shed by Jon Skeet the mighty `Linq` Jedi Knight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to be able to declare which property to update by giving the `AddOne` method a lambda expression. In this case, it's possible -- you can write an extension method that takes an `Expression<T>`, retrieves from this expression the property access expression, and uses Reflection to update that property on the `A` object.

The following is a very rough prototype of the above:

```
public static void AddOne<S,T>(this S x, Expression<Func<S,T>> expr)
{
    if (expr.Body.NodeType != ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
        throw new InvalidOperationException();

    MemberExpression memberExpr = expr.Body as MemberExpression;
    switch (memberExpr.Member.MemberType)
    {
        case MemberTypes.Field:
            {
                FieldInfo field = memberExpr.Member as FieldInfo;
                ulong value = Convert.ToUInt64(field.GetValue(x));
                ++value;
                field.SetValue(x, Convert.ChangeType(value, field.FieldType));
                break;
            }
        case MemberTypes.Property:
            {
                PropertyInfo prop = memberExpr.Member as PropertyInfo;
                ulong value = Convert.ToUInt64(prop.GetValue(x, null));
                ++value;
                prop.SetValue(x, Convert.ChangeType(value, prop.PropertyType), null);
                break;
            }
        default:
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```